# Is $(\mu+\nu)(A)=\mu(A)+\nu(A)$?

Tags: measure-theory

In my textbook they use the notation $(\mu+\nu)(A)$ for two measures.

Is it the same as writing $(\mu+\nu)(A)=\mu(A)+\nu(A)$?

Comment: It may depend on what textbook you are reading, but if they mean anything else, my advice would be to throw the book across the room.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Thanks, I take that as a yes